# GWT RPC call on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, gwt, gwt-rpc

I have a problem with deploying a gwt application on Tomcat, when I call my RPC service with this way it works very well :

```
this.service=GWT.create(MyService.class);
ServiceDefTarget endpoint = (ServiceDefTarget) this.service;
endpoint.setServiceEntryPoint("2_rpc_project/myserviceclass");
```

But what I want exactly is to call my RPC service using the localhost like this :

```
this.service=GWT.create(MyService.class);
ServiceDefTarget endpoint = (ServiceDefTarget) this.service;
endpoint.setServiceEntryPoint("http://127.0.0.1:8080/2_rpc_project/myserviceclass");
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.tominto.server.MyServiceImpl
    </servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/2_rpc_project/myserviceclass</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

On GAE it works but on Tomcat no.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you check in developer tools of browser what uri is requested from "endpoint.setServiceEntryPoint("2_rpc_project/myserviceclass");" ?

Comment: Thank you for your response, but how can i do that ?